# Next.js routing breaks after router push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this really frustrating problem with routing in Next.js. So basically I have this group creation system, where you fill out a form, and create a group with a simple http request to a backend. But when I try routing to the subpage /[groupId], with the new id of the group I just created, it changes the url as expected but simply stops ALL routing from rerendering the client, and kind of freezes the page. links, other router pushes, etc., that worked perfectly before the redirect, suddenly stops rerendering the page, but still changes the url and rerenderes the same page the router.push was requested from. This *bug* **ONLY** happens in production and works perfect in development. No erros in the console. No nothing.

What I've tried to solve this:

- Checked all component keys that might've prevented a rerender
- Used the pathname directly - `router.push("/groups/ACTUAL GROUP ID")`
- `router.push(url, null, { unstable_skipClientCache: true })`
- Searched every corner of the internet for a solution

I'm unfortunately unable to share the codebase, but will happily share some bites if needed.

I'm using Nextjs v13.2.3 without app dir.

Any help of any kind would be **greatly** appreciated.

```js
try {
    const onSubmit = () => {
    ...
    const res = await axios(...);

    if (res) {
        router.push({
            pathname: "/groups/[groupId]",
            query: {
                groupId: "NEW ID"
            },
        });
      }
    }
} catch (err) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using a middleware? If so, be aware of a behavior, described in this [GH issue #30938](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30938). I had a similar issue where the routing did not work as well, because of that behavior. To solve this, I stumpled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096326) answer that solved my problem.